# (#200) Requires extended permission:publish_actions android" with only two facebook users

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am having a strange problem with android facebook sdk. Facebook has approved publish_actions permission for my application. It is working fine for any facebook user we logged in, but except **two facebook users** are reporting problems that they cannot share their picture on their timeline. They are getting the following message: "(#200) Requires extended permission:publish_actions android". Can anyone guide me what will be the problem with those two facebook users account? This is not happening with rest of the users.
Thank you.

Comment: The error message clearly tells you what the reason is i.e. "**They didn't approve** _publish\_actions_. You may check if these two users have required permissions using the "app token".

Comment: Remember that users can also decide not to grant your application publish_actions (and they may forget that they decided not to grant it). You need to check this before calling the Graph API to publish on behalf of the user. As @1lastBr3ath said, make sure your app has actually been approved for publish_actions for non admins/developers/testers.